# Problem with Firestore Security Rules based on array attribute

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection **forms** in Firestore with 2 documents as below:
[image: Document 1]

[image: Document 2]

My Firestore security rules look like below:
[image: Firestore Rules]

However, when I try a query like below,

```
    const q1 = query(
      collection(this.fs, 'forms'),
      where('createdBy', '==', this.auth.currentUser.uid)
    );
    collectionData(q1).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }, () => {
    });
```

I get the following error:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Can anybody suggest, what am I doing incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like you are expecting your rules to act as a filter to strip out documents that don't have the user's UID in readableBy.  It doesn't work that way.  [Security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code/rules, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @DougStevenson I might be wrong in understanding the section in documentation pointed by you, but If you notice, I am not trying to use security rules as filter. My query is based on created by where as my security rule is based on createdBy. I also make sure via my application logic that my query never crosses the boundaries set by my security rules. What I am unable to understand is that I have used this approach in one of my previous firebase application, somehow it’s not working at all this time.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to be able to allow reading the document based on the value of createdBy?  Please edit the question to state your expectation clearly.  Also please observe the convention of using code blocks instead of images.  It will make for more readable and copyable code.